# Standalone PVS-Studio (free) still counts remaining clicks

Tags: pvs-studio

I'm using PVS-Studio Standalone version 6.16.222236. I have added the special comments to all of my files with How-To-Use-PVS-Studio-FREE.exe so I presumed I can use it for free without any trial restrictions.

But after a few runs I saw red text: "Clicks remaining: 0 (can be extended)" and I can't click on any of the diagnostics.

My question is: is that normal? So PVS-Studio will analyze everything for free but the number of clicks is still finite? I'm not saying it's bad or anything, I just want to know if that's the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you forgot to state registration information in PVS-Studio settings (Registration section). You need to write in the Name section - `PVS-Studio Free`, Serial Number - `FREE-FREE-FREE-FREE` for the free version to work.

Despite the fact that you use Standalone utility but not a plugin for Visual Studio, you still need to state registration information in the way it is described in the article "[How to use PVS-Studio for Free](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0457/)".

Please, let us know if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, manual clearly says: "If you are using PVS-Studio as a Visual Studio plugin, enter the following license key". Standalone is not mentioned at all :) Thank you, that worked!